# Stacking two divs on top of each other

Tags: html, css

I have two buttons but they're displaying side by side. I'd like to have them be on top of each other.

```
<div id="top">
    <div>
        <label for="entityDropDown">Entity: </label>
        <select id="entityDropDown"></select>
        <div id="removeEntity"><a>✖</a></div>
    </div>          
    <br><br>
    <div id="entityStatus">
        <div>
            <label for="entityAvailable">Entity Available</label>
            <select id="entityAvailable" multiple=""></select>
        </div>
        <div id="moveButtons">
            <button type="button">Add User</button>
            <button type="button">Remove</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="entityAssigned">Entity Assigned</label>
            <select id="entityAssigned" multiple=""></select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br style="clear:both;">
</div>
```

This is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vS9vJ/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>Group them in an `inline-block` box and</del> set their `display` to `block`. In your JSFiddle they are already in a `inline-block` container, so you won't need to specify that again.

In code:

```
#moveButtons button{
    display: block;
}
```

You can then align vertically the boxes using the property `vertical-align`, for example, try this:

```
#entityStatus div {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/vS9vJ/3/

Comment: you solution looks the best. I tried to copy all the css into my code but it doesn't look like it does in the fiddle. Strange.

Comment: In the Fiddle I also set a `margin: 0 auto;` for the buttons (to center them horizontally), but I don't think it's that. What's the difference?

Comment: they're just laid out side by side, it's better thought because now at least they are vertically aligned in the middle, just not stacked

Comment: Have you tried to use an inspector to see if there is some other rule overriding that property?

Comment: I tried it again in the fiddle with your css but yea it's not working http://jsfiddle.net/fwh2S/

Comment: You changed the `id` of the element, you set it like a class, but it isn't a class...

Comment: wow. Idiot mistake. No wonder the style wasn't showing up in the console. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Simply:

```
#moveButtons button {
    display:block;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/vS9vJ/1/

Answer (score 3):

Just add this to your CSS:

```
#moveButtons button {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```